# SFML Memory leaks

Tags: memory-leaks, sfml

So I started playing around with the SFML library and I get lots of memory leaks just by creating a simple program that draws a window. Any solution to this?

```
int main()
{

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(SCREEN_X, SCREEN_Y), APP_TITLE);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
        {
            if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
            {


            }
        }
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

    window.display();
}

_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: SFML uses some global state that are only cleaned up when the program exists. Also you should give us the actual leaks you've found. But above all: is it pertinent to put energy in it? Are leaks growing up when the app run for a long time or not? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out that CRT falsely reports memory leaks. Actually there are no leaks whatsoever. I installed a plugin for VS and now everything is fine.